# Do questions closed as exact duplicates still get auto-suggested when people type their titles in?

Tags: discussion

And also, does this still happen even if the question closed as an exact duplicate ends up deleted?

The one thing is that there are many ways to phrase a single question - and people might not always discover the duplicate for the first time. But when duplicates are merged, then does this help more people discover the original question? (sort of like what happens on Quora when questions are merged?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do. You could know this by simply finding a closed question and typing in some keywords from its title.

[image: example]

If it got deleted, it would not show up because you can't view it. I'm not sure exactly how merging works. I'd assume some sort of suggestion would show up if the question got merged with another, possibly the question that it was merged into instead (since that URL would now redirect there). Usually when things get merged, the better (more detailed) title of the two gets used on the question. I can't find any examples of a question which kept its original title after something was merged into it (not that I searched a *ton*, but I did search).

Comment: Yeah - what I am also wondering is this: do questions closed as duplicates often end up deleted after a few months?